# Fastest way to generate patches from an image/array and save the coordinates

Tags: python, keras

I have trained a CNN with Keras in order to segment specific patterns. It works really well, but now I have to start the "production phase", so my CNN must segment thousands of images.

So for a given image that the CNN has to segment, for each pixel into this image, I have to cut a patch around the pixel, and feed the CNN with all the patches. So far I used this solution:

```
WindowSize = 23 #patch size
ws2 = WindowSize / 2
image_data = ndimage.imread(image_file).astype(float)
dimensions = image_data.shape
SizeX = dimensions[1]
SizeY = dimensions[0]
imtest = np.ndarray(shape=(SizeX-2*ws2, 1, WindowSize, WindowSize), dtype=np.float32)
for y in range(ws2,SizeY-ws2):
    for x in range(ws2,SizeX-ws2):
        imtest[x-ws2,0] = image_data[y-ws2:y+ws2+1, x-ws2:x+ws2+1]
```

So I work row by row, like that I don't loose the patch coordinates. But **this solution is really slow. Is there a faster way to do it?**

I've also heard about the Generator in Keras, but it seems to be useful to train a generator with the fit_generator function, but not to test on an image and then to segment it because you it does not keep the patches coordinates.

Comment: If your images all have the same size and the patches are all the same you can use a static input mask for each sample or use a static mask (a matrix with ones and zeros) for each image instead of the row-wise computation.

Comment: Could please elaborate on your answer, I am new to python and Keras.

Comment: I've looked online for "static input mask", but I've found anything useful. Any help?

Comment: Another possible solution would be to build a class that either returns a list or a list generator of the patch coordinates (will save a lot of ram), and then use those coordinates to grab pixel patches from the image. Only way this might be slow is if you need to to local pre-processing on those patches before feeding into your CNN

Answer (score 2):

> Here is a way to generate images with keras, hope it helps:

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=.06,
    width_shift_range=0.02,
    height_shift_range=0.02,
    shear_range=0.0002,
    zoom_range=0.0002,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode='nearest',
    rescale = 1/255.
    )

for X_batch, y_batch in datagen.flow(X_train, y_train, batch_size=9):
  for i in range(0, 9):
    pyplot.subplot(330 + 1 + i)
    pyplot.imshow(X_batch[i].reshape(128, 128, 3),    
    cmap=pyplot.get_cmap('gray'))
  pyplot.show()
  break
```

Comment: Thanks for  your answer. Is that really faster than what I did?

Comment: this is a generator function and it is called in real time when training, so it definitely occupies less RAM than your approach. But with your approach you can pre generate the image and store them on disk and load them, so if you were to try train with multiples hyper parameters it helps

Comment: As I said into my post, I've already training my CNN, I am into the production phase. So I need all the possible patches from an image, then give them to the CNN for testing/evaluation, and finally put the answer back into the an image in order to measure/evalute the segmentation results.